# Stream Reader/Writer for RTSP WinRT Client App

Tags: stream, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, rtsp, inputstreamreader

I have spend hours to convert an old net v2 project and to port it to WinRT in C#.
Its a RTSP client thats sending commands to a DVBservice (DVBViewer). So, at this moment, the WinForm Program has been renewed and its working prety fine. Connecting, sending and receiving  commands to the server and finaly the stream to my localhost UDP port are fully working and the ts stream is fully readable via VLC and RTP protocol.

But now, i'd like to write my Metro app with this stuff. I managed to do the work and seems to be almost finish (at least the Socket and stream stuff).

But now, I'm getting stuck on a stupid problem. I CAN'T communicate with the RTSP Server.
My Stream Reader/Writer is'nt working and I've tried a lot.

The app is based on code from the Uniriotec.DV project, so for any futher info, you can find it by google.

So, here's the point I'm getting stuck:
Its the main handle, thats getting the StreamSocket  with the Stream (the messages) together.

```
//Set input and output stream filters in the main client app
RTSPBufferedReader = new BufferedReader<Stream> (RTSPsocket);
RTSPBufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter<Stream> (RTSPsocket);

namespace RTSP.Client
{
    public class BufferedReader<T> : StreamReader where T : Stream
    {
        private StreamSocket socket;
        private T unbufferedStream;
        private StreamSocket streamSocket;

        public T UnbufferedStream
        {
            get { return unbufferedStream; }
            set { unbufferedStream = value; }
        }

        public BufferedReader(T myStream)
            : base(myStream)
        {
            unbufferedStream = myStream;
        }

        public BufferedReader(StreamSocket mySocket)
            : base(new Stream(mySocket)) // <== here is the problem, saying "could'nt establish an instance of the abstract or interface class "System.IO.Stream"....
        {
            this.streamSocket = mySocket;
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea where I did the error?

Thanks for answering,
Jo

---

PS: I need await writer.StoreAsync();  because the answer is send approx 10-15 sec. later, when the server is ready to thread the request and sends me SessionID and so back.

Comment: Update (edit) your question instead of posting updates as answers.

Answer (score 0):

The Stream class is abstract and you cannot instantiate an abstract class directly, like you are doing with the base(new Stream(mySocket)). See here for the System.IO.Stream definition
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.io.stream.aspx

You need to replace the Stream class with the appropriate derived class, such as DataReader. Here is an example of using a StreamSocket sample that may help:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931

Comment: Hi, and many thanks. I did that already and been working with this sample. Now I understand better what I have to do.

Comment: What I dont get is, HOW and WHY its been working in a normal Winxx app. Is a RT app so different?

Comment: to be honest, not sure why that exact code was working previously since the Stream class has always been abstract. There are some major changes with a few things in winRT, take a look here for some notable changes: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302.aspx)

Once you get the hang of the winRT api it is much cleaner (and easier) to implement many things.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I've rewritten the stack, without the use of any line of the old projekt. Guess what .... ;-) Maybe 1/10 of code lines. But ok,... I did it just for the code I absolutely needed. Anyway, thanks a lot!!! You gave me the right direction.

Comment: your welcome! if you could please mark this as the answer it will help guide others to the correct place.